# Excel file download in C# not working in Google Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This code is working when I am going to download a file using IE but when I tried in google chrome, it is not working. Why?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Excel_Reports() {          
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        //events query
        var events = db.Events_Info_tbl.Where(x => x.is_active == true).FirstOrDefault();
        ViewBag.events_name = events.events_name;

        var details = from cat in db.Events_Category_tbl
                      join can in db.Candidates_Info_tbl on cat.events_category_id equals can.events_category_id
                      where cat.events_info_id == events.events_info_id
                      select new Candidates
                      {
                          events_category_name = cat.events_category_name,
                          candidates_fullname = can.candidates_fullname,
                          candidates_info_id = can.candidates_info_id,
                          events_category_id = cat.events_category_id,
                          no_of_votes = can.no_of_votes.Value
                      };

        return View(details);

    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but how it is `C`?

Comment: He is telling about the tag. You have tagged this question as `C` where as it should be `C#` and its already edited by @Yu Hao.

Comment: Ahh,,okay..Im sorry for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Excel_Reports() {          
        //events query
        var events = db.Events_Info_tbl.Where(x => x.is_active == true).FirstOrDefault();
        ViewBag.events_name = events.events_name;

        var details = from cat in db.Events_Category_tbl
                      join can in db.Candidates_Info_tbl on cat.events_category_id equals can.events_category_id
                      where cat.events_info_id == events.events_info_id
                      select new Candidates
                      {
                          events_category_name = cat.events_category_name,
                          candidates_fullname = can.candidates_fullname,
                          candidates_info_id = can.candidates_info_id,
                          events_category_id = cat.events_category_id,
                          no_of_votes = can.no_of_votes.Value
                      };

        HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename= Election_Results " + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + ".xls");
        this.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

        return View(details);
    }
```

This is my revised code and it works both in IE and Google Chrome.